# Why is geom_smooth not showing in my graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

Do you have any idea why this code is not returning a linear regression line on the plot?

```
ggplot(data = df3, mapping = aes(x = work_growth, y = gdp_growth, col = RegionCode))+
  geom_point()+
  labs (x= "Growth rate of the working-age population",y = "Growth rate of GDP per capita") +
  geom_smooth(method="lm")+
  theme_classic() + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

This is plot I get:[image: 1]

Here is the dataframe I'm working with for reference: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19XvX_gxlPAmhct9jXfUSd5GPcEQFM4eD/view?usp=sharing

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Try with `geom_smooth(aes(group=1), method = "lm")`. As you map  `RegionCode` on the color aes your data gets grouped by `RegionCode` and I would suspect that geom_smooth fails as there is only one obs. per Region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do the plot of the "smooth" first, you can then plot the points later with an `aes()` call using the `regionCode` as a color argument

[image]

```
ggplot(data = dat, mapping = aes(x = work_growth, y = gdp_growth))+
    labs (x= "Growth rate of the working-age population",y = "Growth rate of GDP per capita") +
    geom_smooth(method="lm")+ 
    geom_point(aes(col=RegionCode))+
    theme_classic() + theme(legend.position = "none")
```